# SSIS Derived Column Transformation only write value if true. If without else

Tags: ssis, data-conversion

I want to convert a boolean to an int and write the value to a column, where already data exists. So only overwrite data if the boolean is true. How do I achieve this. It's like an if without an else:
(DT_I4)([columnName] == "Ja" ? 896320001 : ***do nothing***)
Or is the derived column transformation the wrong way at all?

Answer (score 0):

Consider a null handler:

```
([columnName] == "Ja" ? (DT_I4)896320001 : (DT_I4)null)
```

If this doesn't answer your question, consider adding sample source data and expected results. It really helps follow your pattern better.

Comment: Okay I try to explain it in a better way.
I have a column statuscode which can have the values 1,2,3....
The column exists in both source and destination.
In source I have also a boolean column 'deceased' which should be mapped to the statuscode with value 3 if it's set to true
So my mapping should something like this:
statuscode
1 --> 1 / 
2 --> 2
....
deceased / statuscode
1 --> 3 / 
0 --> leave statuscode it as it is

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment I suggest creating a new Mapped_Status_Code by testing the deceased field like this in a derived column:

```
Mapped_Status_Code = Deceased ? 3 : StatusCode
```

This assumes deceased is already Boolean otherwise use what is in there like this:

```
Mapped_Status_Code = Deceased == "YES" ? 3 : StatusCode
```

By adding the mapped column, you can always see what the source was. This will help with debugging later.

There are other ways to do this (especially if you have a lot of tests), but this is the simplest approach.